# How can I calculate the mean and maximum value for 4D image data?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, max, mean

I have some 4D image data, 384-by-276-by-20-by-5, where `data(X,Y,T,V)`, `X = x location`, `Y = y location`, `T = time`, `V = vessel location`.

I would like to have a mean value over time and maximum value over time for the data to get the pattern of my signal and thus set the value of my threshold value. I do it in loop so I could get say, for example `data(1,1,:,1)`, a mean value for that point over time.

I tried `mean(data(X,Y,:,V))` and `mean(squeeze(data(X,Y,:,V)))` but it is giving me the error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."

I search everywhere but the example of mean value are only for 2D and 1D. I reckon, if I want to get a mean/max value of the data over time, the data is to be `data(X,Y,:,V)` which is now 3D data.

Any help or idea about how to do this?

Comment: If the answers provided are sufficient to solve your issue, could you mark the most appropriate one as the "accepted answer" by clicking on the check mark next to it? This also helps other people see that this question is solved...

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the dimension over which to take the mean by passing it as a second parameter to the [MEAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mean.html) function. Then you can remove singleton dimensions using the [SQUEEZE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/squeeze.html) function to get a 3-D matrix:

```
meanData = squeeze(mean(data,3));
```

The same procedure can be followed for finding the maximum using the [MAX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/max.html) function, although you will have to add an empty parameter `[]` before you specify the dimension to operate over:

```
maxData = squeeze(max(data,[],3));
```

Comment: thank you @gnovice. I just realize my problem.. i fix it by giving a preallocating and define the mean result to be in a matrix function..

Answer (score 1):

To analyze your problem, start from the error message: "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals." Do you understand what it means? If not, does it contain words you are not sure what they mean? Can you read up about them in the documentation? Can you google the whole error message?

The reason behind this is that you need to understand how MATLAB accesses elements of your 384-by-276-by-20-by-5 array; your problem has nothing to do with taking means or maxima, therefore searching for those terms didn't help.

When you type

```
data(X,Y,T,V)
```

then X,Y,T,V need to be integers (or vectors of integers), i.e. X must be in the range 1:384 and so on. For example,

```
mean(data(1,1,:,1))
```

will give you the temporal mean for the first X,Y and V points.

That said, you were saying you use a loop... have a look at what

```
mean(data,3)
```

and

```
max(data,[],3)
```

do... this should completely replace your loop if I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: Thank you. I definitely understand what it means here. The data I have are all positive values, therefore, I dont quite understand why the error is like that.
Yes, I want a temporal value of the data. apparently i dont have problem of value being replaced since i put them in an icremental loop 1:X,1:y,1:T,1:V and assign the result in a matrix value. I try to run the algotihm again with gnovice and @Jacob code and giving a preallocating and it is currently working fine. thanks!

Comment: If you get this error message, it means you are not feeding integers. Could it be that X, Y or V can have a value like 1.2 or something?

Answer (score 1):

`mean(data,3)` and 
`max(data,[],3)`